# How to I get linguex to give me (i)-numbered footnotes when using endnotes?

Tags: numbering, footnotes, examples, endnotes, linguex

I need to convert all footnotes to endnotes, but I want numbered examples internal to the notes to be numbered with lowercase roman numerals, as is standard with linguex footnotes.

The linguex document has a note which says

> Such style files must be accommodated to linguex.sty by making
>   sure that \if@noftnote is set false at the beginning of each footnote (by saying
>   \@noftnotefalse in the modified footnote definition); otherwise you will get
>   the arabic style of example numberings (as being used in the main text) rather
>   than the roman numbers (being used inside footnotes).

But I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

I tried:

```
\usepackage{endnotes}

\makeatletter
\let\footnote=\@noftnotefalse\footnote
\makeatother

\let\footnote=\endnote
```

Which indeed made the numbered examples in the endnotes have lowercase roman numerals, but it also made all of the examples in the main text have lowercase roman numerals as well (and seemed to create some weirdness with the actual numerical ordering in the main text).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you just want you `\ex` to know it is in a footnote when we are printing the end notes.  So it is sufficient to issue `\@noftnotefalse` just before `\theendnotes`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{linguex}

\let\footnote\endnote

\begin{document}

\ex. This is the first level of embedding
  \a. This is the second level
  \b. This is still the second level, but:
    \a. This is the third level 
    \b. This is not the end\footnote{A comment}. 
    \b. This is the end.

Text and text\footnote{A different example would be:
\ex. This is the first level of embedding 
  \a. This is the second level
  \b. This is still the second level, but:
    \a. This is the third level 
    \b. This is not the end. 
    \b. This is the end.\par}.

\bigskip
\makeatletter\@noftnotefalse\makeatother
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

If there is material after your end notes, then you should issue `\@noftnotetrue` in a similar way just after `\theendnotes`.